# lambda duration to hour

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have entered the following code to get duration into hours

```
quiz_df['hours'] = quiz_df['duration'].apply(lambda time: time.total_seconds()/60/60)
```

the format of the duration is `10 days 03:35:00`

```
it returns the error AttributeError: 'numpy.timedelta64' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

I have tried converting it to seconds then hours it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `apply` to do this. You can access `timedelta64` functionality with the `dt` accessor.

```
pd.to_timedelta(quiz_df.duration).dt.total_seconds()/3600
```

Answer (score 0):

```
quiz_df['hours'] = quiz_df['duration'].apply(lambda time: pd.Timedelta(time).total_seconds() / 3600.0)
```

works all good.

Comment: Try and avoid `apply` whenever possible. It can be horrendously slow. You can convert an entire sequence with `pd.to_timedelta`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!